# Apper and Discover says network is offline?

Tags: debian, networking, application

I installed Devuan Linux in VMWare workstation 16 bridged network.  Network via the terminal works fine, using ping, using apt-get, ifconfig etc.. I then tried firefox in the GUI and that worked fine too.

However, when I try to use apper or discover via the GUI menu, they both say the network is offline?   Also when I click on the network icon in the task bar (using kde) it comes up blank, I can configure and edit the wired network setting (which I deleted and created again to see if fixed) but that wired network never shows in the list when clicking on the network icon, it only shows when clicking option to configure once at the list.  Not sure if that has anything to do with it?

Anyone have the fix to get these GUI package managers to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and set

```
[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

then restart network-manager :

`service network-manager restart`